# systemd-networkd won't configure a static IP

Tags: networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to switch to a static IP address, but systemd keeps using DHCP.  Here is my `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` file:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=192.168.5.100/24
DHCP=no
```

I know the file is being read because if I put a bad setting in that file, I'll see a warning message in systemctl status.

Here are `systemctl status systemd-networkd` results:

```
[[0;1;32m●[[0m systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: [[0;1;32mactive (running)[[0m since Wed 2020-12-16 17:25:20 UTC; 32s ago
TriggeredBy: [[0;1;32m●[[0m systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
   Main PID: 137 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1141)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             └─137 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Dec 16 17:25:19 beaglebone-yocto systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Dec 16 17:25:20 beaglebone-yocto systemd-networkd[137]: Enumeration completed
Dec 16 17:25:20 beaglebone-yocto systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Dec 16 17:25:21 beaglebone-yocto systemd-networkd[137]: eth0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Dec 16 17:25:21 beaglebone-yocto systemd-networkd[137]: eth0: Link UP
Dec 16 17:25:24 beaglebone-yocto systemd-networkd[137]: eth0: Gained carrier
Dec 16 17:25:25 beaglebone-yocto systemd-networkd[137]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Dec 16 17:25:28 beaglebone-yocto systemd-networkd[137]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 10.1.1.61/16 via 10.1.0.1
```

Finally, here are results for `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:a3:16:bb:c6:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.61/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86322sec preferred_lft 86322sec
    inet6 fe80::6a3:16ff:febb:c60a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong.  It's reading the file, and giving no errors, but it's still using DHCP.

Comment: Is there maybe another config file that overrides the setting? See the man page for `systemd.network` for the processing order.

Comment: Yes!  Exactly that.  There was a file in /lib/systemd/network that was setting DHCP for ALL wired networks.  Great idea.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to switch to a static IP address, but systemd keeps using DHCP

> Yes! Exactly that. There was a file in /lib/systemd/network that was setting DHCP for ALL wired networks. Great idea. Thanks!

It's because you didn't prefix your file with a number. Quoting `man systemd.network`:

> It is recommended that each filename is prefixed with a number (e.g. `10-eth0.network`). Otherwise, the default `.network` files or those generated by systemd-network-generator.service(8) may take precedence over user configured files.

So what happens is that system defaults override your user-defined configuration. To avoid that rename your file from `eth0.network` to e.g. `10-eth0.network`.